# Shift to Parent View Controller from child view controller - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parent-child, parentviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I have a main Actions View Controller, and on that there is button "Review". Review Button's functionality is :

```
 - (IBAction)btnReview:(id)sender
{
    ReviewViewController *vc = [[ReviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}
```

Now on Review Page, I have a button. And on that button's action, I want to switch back to Parent View Controller. Its view should be displayed. I have tried following code, it either pauses or crashes application.

```
[self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

I even tried:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

I have read other posts related to this question as well but could not find a satisfactory answer. Please Help!

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem here, but you shouldn't have to call `didMoveToParentViewController:` with a `nil` parameter, `removeFromParentViewController` should call that automatically after the view controller was removed.

Comment: even if I remove [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];, it still pauses the application and later on crashes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that this is a custom viewcontroller container you're trying to build, "self" is the Main Actions viewController you're talking about.

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)btnReview:(id)sender
{
    ReviewViewController *vc = [[ReviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReviewViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:vc];

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];

    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    vc = nil;

}
```

For the "Back" button, I'm assuming this is the Button to return to Main Actions viewController from the Review viewController, try this:

```
- (IBAction)btnReviewHide:(id)sender
 {

    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use delegation. When you click the button in your `ReviewViewController`, you call a method like: `[self.delegate hideReviewController:self];`

And this method would look something like:

```
- (void)hideReviewController:(ReviewViewController *)controller {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                             animations:^{
                                  controller.view.alpha = 0;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                  [self.view removeSubview:controller.view];
                                  // If you want the Review Controller to be deallocated:
                                  [self removeChildViewController:controller];
                             }];
}
```

**EDIT:**
In your ReviewDelegate.h file add:

```
@class ReviewViewController;

@protocol ReviewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)hideReviewController:(ReviewViewController *)controller;
@end
```

Then add this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ReviewDelegate> delegate;
```

In the parent class:

```
 - (IBAction)btnReview:(id)sender
{
    ReviewViewController *vc = [[ReviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}

    - (void)hideReviewController:(ReviewViewController *)controller {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                      delay:0
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                 animations:^{
                                      controller.view.alpha = 0;
                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      [self.view removeSubview:controller.view];
                                      // If you want the Review Controller to be deallocated:
                                      [self removeChildViewController:controller];
                                 }];
    }
```

I also suggest that you read about [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
self.view=nil;
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make it complex... Just use `UINavigationController`.

To navigate from `ParentVC` to `ChildVC` :

```
  ChildViewController *ChildVC = [[ChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ChildVC animated:YES];
```

And for navigating back from `ChildVC` to `ParentVC` :

```
ParentViewController *ParentVC = [[ParentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ParentViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Navigating from ParentVC to ChildVC is working fine, but crashes when navigating back from ChildVC to ParentVC.

Comment: Have you implemented 'pushViewController:' for navigation from ParentVC to ChildVC????

Comment: Have you implemented `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in your interface file of your parentVC as well as in ChildVC.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the Child View as a Subview on to Parent you need to manually it from its superview (in your case parentview). Rather then adding it as a subview you can make use of presentViewController method as follow:

```
 - (IBAction)btnReview:(id)sender
  {

   ReviewViewController *vc = [[ReviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReviewViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self presentViewController:vc
                      animated:YES
                    completion:nil];
  }
```

and in the child class code for back button will be :

```
  -(IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender
  {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for could be taken care of with a `UINavigationController`. Just use `pushViewController:` to push the new view onto the screen. Then, a back button will appear in the navigation bar atop the view, which can be used to return to the "parent" view controller.

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: No, I am not using UINavigationController, as my application is Tab based.

Comment: See Levi's answer above, then.

Answer (score 0):

writing only

```
- (IBAction)backbutton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

worked in my case